# passing dataclass as default parameter

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have some dataclass with default values:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class SomeDataclass:
    field: str = ""
    number: int = 3
```

I have a function that receives that as a parameter. I want to enable it to receive empty parameter, which will cause it to instantiate a default dataclass. This is the behavior I want:

```
def func(instance: SomeDataClass = None):
    # I want to get rid of these lines
    if instance is None:
        instance = SomeDataClass()
```

Is that possible somehow without explicitly doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function will not modify the instance of `SomeDataclass`, you can safely use

```
def func(instance: SomeDataClass = SomeDataclass()):
    ...
```

The check-for-`None` idiom is used when each call to the function should gets its own, new instance of a *mutable* value (like a `list`, `dict`, or `set`).

Otherwise, no: you need a sentinel to indicate whether or not `func` should instantiate `SomeDataclass` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define the class on the fly an instantiate it on the fly as well.

The main issue here is that we define the class twice.

So I dont think its the way to go until we can have a way to define the class only once.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
import dataclasses

@dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    f: str = 'jack'
    number: int = 12
                   

def foo(data=dataclasses.make_dataclass('SomeDataClass',[('f',str,field(default='jack')),('number', int,field(default=12))])()):
  print(data)

foo()
foo(SomeDataClass('jim',33))
```

output

```
SomeDataClass(f='jack', number=12)
SomeDataClass(f='jim', number=33)
```

Comment: That's a big issue. What benefit is there to defining a new class?